# How do I create a JSON format with types and conditions using Json Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Right now, I'm creating a json with the following fields: 1. Name of user 2. Which country they live in 3. When did they register to site 4. Current job  5. Does the client use contracts when engaging with clients  6. Number of houses they own. This is used for the user to answer the question.

The 5th field should only render if their current job (4th field) is a lawyer. If they are not a lawyer, the field shouldn't render. Similarly, the 6th field should only render if their job is real estate agent.

What I initially did was just over simplified json as so:

```
{
   "name" : "My Company",
   "country" : "TX",
   "registration date" : "2019-01-01",
   "Current Job" : "lawyer",
   "always use contracts" : "yes",
   "Number of houses" : 1
}
```

This is a filled out json. I want to make one that has inputs for a question. How can I set conditional statements in the json so fields are chosen depending on previous answers?

Comment: generating forms from JSON Schema is non standard. You'll have to provide the specific library you're using and the schema you have so far. You'll also have to look at the documentation for that specific library to see what they support. What you ask may not be possible with that library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to build conditional dependency: billing address is necessary only when there is `credit_card` field

```js
{
  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "name": { "type": "string" },
    "credit_card": { "type": "number" }
  },

  "required": ["name"],

  "dependencies": {
    "credit_card": {
      "properties": {
        "billing_address": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["billing_address"]
    }
  }
}
```

https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies/#conditional